# Is running a script in 5 powershell windows simultaneously, the same as multithreading with 5 threads?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, sharepoint

My aim is to delete 1000 items in a list. I am deleting the first 20 items from a script in the first powershell window, the next 20 items from the same list in the second window and so on. My question is will they execute asynchronously? Is it the same as multithreading with 5 threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Powershell window runs in its own process, so yes they will run asynchronously.

Comment: Not that this is not correct but Powershell has multiple built-in options to work asynchronously without resorting to opening a shell x times. Workflows, jobs, -parallel and probably forgetting some...

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Are you saying that all Powershell windows share the same process?

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. Yes there are better methods for Powershell to work asynchronously, but is outside of the scope of the question.